# AWS DynamoDB | Can DynamoDB set server side timestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS DynamoDB as a database for an app.

**Question:** Is it possible for DynamoDB to make a server side timestamp?

Example:

```
    let db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
    db.put({
      TableName: 'foo-table',
      Item: {
        uuid: 'very unique uuid',
        timestamp: new Date().getTime() //I want DynamoDB to set this timestamp
                               }
      }, (err, data) => {//left out});
```

As you can see in the example the client sets the timestamp with `new Date().getTime()`

This is problematic, since `Date` uses OS time and thereby is open to manipulation (or different time zones).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you don't trust the client then your code could get the current time from an external, trusted time source. And write it as ISO8601 or epoch time, not local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust the client to set the timestamp, then enable DynamoDB streams.  You can have a lambda trigger off that DyanmoDB stream which should enable you to have an approximate timestamp you can trust.  Have your lambda then update the record with your modified timestamp.